# Is it implied that Porpetina and Queenie Goldstein are Jewish?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, jk-rowling, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

J.K Rowling has said on Twitter that Porpetina and Queenie Goldstein are [distantly related to Anthony Goldstein](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/632611629843263488),

> **J.K. Rowling** ‏@jk_rowling
>
> Well, I think it's widely known that that characters of (Porpen)tina and Queenie are sisters, but not that their surname is Goldstein.
>
> **Mark** ‏@marklynch2012
>
> any rlation to Anthony Goldstein
>
> **J.K. Rowling** ‏@jk_rowling
>
> Yes (but distant).

whom she has previously [confirmed to be Jewish](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/544946669448867841).

> **ben** ‏@benjaminroffman
>
> @jk_rowling my wife said there are no Jews at Hogwarts. I’m a Jew so I assume she said it to be the only magical 1 in the family. Thoughts?
>
> **J.K. Rowling** ‏@jk_rowling
>
> Anthony Goldstein, Ravenclaw, Jewish wizard.

Was she trying to say that they are Jewish as well?

Comment: you might want to clarify if you mean, religiously Jewish, or heritage/race Jewish.

Comment: @Himarm any of those would be good.

Comment: It's funny, they don't looks Druish.... </obligatory_Mel_Brooks>

Comment: Also, in all fairness, "distantly related" can mean a lot of things. I'm very distantly related to Temuchin and Ceasar, I'm sure. Given the inbreeding in Wizarding Britain, everyone's more related to everyone else than European Royalty

Comment: @DVK, are you really sure about Ceasar? :)

Comment: @Dima - well, even if he didn't have children, bastard or not, he had other relatives up the family tree :)

Comment: @DVK - The guy who invented the salad?

Comment: ...Their last name is Goldstein. It's an Azshkenazi Jew name.

Comment: @Axelrod - also, German. Not conclusive

Comment: @DVK by occam's razor, they would have the last name because of being related to Anthony, who had it as a Jewish name, not a German name. Still doesn't show them to be Jewish though.

Comment: @DVK It's a name that was assigned to Jews by the Europeans, to set them apart. Also it's charged (Jews have gold~) to increase anti-Jew sentiment.

Comment: @ibid - we are talking about universe where Time-Turners exist and there's no conservation of matter, energy or momentum. WHAT Occam's razor?

Comment: @DVK I guess than that it's similar to "Evans", where two characters have the same last name for completely different reasons. (Just that here they also happen to be related.)

Comment: [This article](http://www.hypable.com/fantastic-beasts-cast/) claims "J.K. Rowling recently revealed that Tina and Queenie are Jewish", but I think it's just referring to the tweet about them being related to Anthony, so not really reliable.

Comment: @randal'thor reminds me of [Citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/).

Comment: Pfft. Magic is for all y'all who didnt get to be a jew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Likely yes - the actress playing Queenie says Queenie is Jewish.

It seems likely that Queenie Goldstein is indeed Jewish - Alison Sudol, the actress who plays her says that she’s glad to be playing a Jewish character and she’s proud of who Queenie is.

> Alison (and all of us, really) loves that Queenie is “so unapologetically feminine”, and also said she’s proud to be playing a Jewish character:
>
> “It’s a really cool thing. Diversity is important. I’m really proud of who she is.” 
> <sub><sup>*[- Alison Sudol’s ‘Fantastic Beasts’ Panel at LeakyCon 2018 (The Leaky Cauldron)](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2018/08/13/alison-sudols-fantastic-beasts-panel-at-leakycon-2018/)*</sup></sub>

Alison Sudol, at least, seems to think that Queenie is Jewish, so would likely be playing her with the intention of her being Jewish. She doesn’t mention if she knows or thinks Queenie’s sister Tina is also Jewish, but she certainly believes that her own character Queenie  is Jewish.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, there is no canon answer to your question. That said, I don't think it would be out of line to consider these two characters could indeed be Jewish.

I'm sorry to leave such a nebulous answer, but there simply isn't further information (that I was able to find on the Harry Potter Lexicon or Pottermore) available on Porpetina and Queenie Goldstein.

I can say, interestingly, that for *years*, many in the Harry Potter fandom thought there was a character named "Queenie Greengrass", and they attributed this to Slytherin student Daphne Greengrass having a sibling named Queenie. It was only when J.K. Rowling revealed Astoria Greengrass (who went on to marry Draco Malfoy, and who was an ardent supporter of peace between pure-bloods, half-bloods, and Muggleborns) was Daphne's younger sister, and Queenie Goldstein was distantly related to Anthony Goldstein, that fandom stood corrected. Just a vaguely related trivia tidbit.

Comment: That's what people get for thinking The Original Forty is canon.

Comment: @ibid - Han Shot First.

Comment: @Slytherincess:  How do the facts you listed lead to the previous assumption of a character named "Queenie Greengrass".   I don't understand.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - "The Original Forty".